# Read the output of a command into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, read

I am making a bash script but I'm totally new and got lost.

I've made this code

```
cat * | grep "|*parameter1*|" | grep "|*parameter2*|" | cut -f 8,11,12,15,21,23,34 -d "|" | wc -l
```

which works just fine, but I need to read the `wc -l` output into a variable so I can make an average after that with another bash command. Then, print out that average and make it readable to the user.

Comment: if you post some input sample, then using awk we can make it better.

Comment: if just want to count pattern match then use `awk '( /\|parameter1\|/ || /\|paramater2\|/ ) { n++;} END{ print n}' input.file`

Answer (score 3):

To answer your direct question, you need to wrap your code in a `$()` sequence so that its output can be assigned to a variable. Like so:

```
x=$(your_code_goes_here)
```

That said, I have a few notes about your one-liner:

- Why the leading `cat *`? This seems to be a [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat). You can directly do

  ```
  grep pattern *
  ```

  which still might not be a good idea since the `*` would match all files and sub-directories in your current directory and `grep` will throw a warning if you ask it to search in a directory without supplying the `-r` (recursive) option. Using the `*` may or may not be suitable depending on your use case.
- I'm not sure what the `wc -l` at the end is intended for: `cut` doesn't print its output on several lines so `wc -l` (count the number of lines) would always return 1.

Comment: You were right, this is what I needed. I used {cat} because I am gonna write the result into a .txt as well. And that's the reason for the {cut} too

The {wc -l} in this case is needed because i am searching for logs with a specific pattern.

Comment: @baccksash Again, I doubt that `wc -l` is the right choice here. Maybe if you gives us more information on what you're trying to accomplish, we can help you achieve it in an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
var=$(cat * | grep "|*parameter1*|" | grep "|*parameter2*|" | cut -f 8,11,12,15,21,23,34 -d "|" | wc -l)
```